# Can't start service on boot after Android 7

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, boot

I want to start a service on boot. 
This code only works on Android versions that came before 7. 
What should I change to make it work on newer versions? Should I use JobScheduler or maybe WorkManager instead?
For what I know Timer, Handler and AlarmManager are deprecated or have different purposes.
I suspect that after Android 7 they removed the option of starting a service on boot in order to save battery life and avoid slowing down the phone. Can you confirm that?

This is my broadcast receiver

```
package com.kev.boot21;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class BroadcastReceiverOnBootComplete extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("tag","xyz broadcast 1");
        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, AndroidServiceStartOnBoot.class);
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my service

```
package com.kev.boot21;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class AndroidServiceStartOnBoot extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i("tag","xyz service");
    }

}
```

This is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.kev.boot21">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <receiver
            android:name="com.kev.boot21.BroadcastReceiverOnBootComplete"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.kev.boot21.AndroidServiceStartOnBoot"></service>

        <activity
            android:name="com.kev.boot21.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Background execution limits were introduced in Android 8. Have a read through this: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#back-all.

Answer (score 0):

I found that WorkManager is the best way to handle this problem. 
I managed to run a PeriodicWorkRequest after reboot on Android 7, 8 and 9 using the example code from the official documentation:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics

Android 10 behaves in a different way. After reboot the PeriodicWorkRequest works only after opening the app. I guess it's for performance/security reasons

Answer (score -1):

You need to register your receiver in your code by calling Context.registerReceiver(), as ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED is no longer sent to receivers registered through AndroidManifest.xml